# SSIS System.UnathorizedException

Tags: ssis, io

I have an SSIS Package that's running under a proxy id. These SSIS Packages pull data from an MS-SQL Database and save the files to a file. All reports were running fine, until I added a report to a new path.

Visual Studio 2015 Professional, SSIS Package Deploy (SQL 2016 Instance).

The process to save the file to a staging location works fine, then when it tries to move the file to the business lines network location I'm getting the error:

```
An error occurred with the following error message: "Access to the path '\\<snipped path>\' is denied.".
```

I also tried putting it into a script task and got a little bit of a differnt on an error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\<snipped path>' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, 
Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at ST_75f74f9657474c93a5737824dfa58e59.ScriptMain.Main()
```

I've worked with our Info Security Team, and they have verified that the proxy account has access to the path.

Any idea why an SSIS Package would do this? I can't figure out why it would throw this error if the account has access.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a file task that is contained within a foreach enumerator then you are running into a locking issue. Instead of trying to `Move` the file, select `Rename` and provide the fully qualified name (i.e., `\\networkpath\filename.extension`).

Comment: I will try that now.. I am using a For Each. Why would it work for all the other files, but just not this specific path? I'll let you know the results.

Comment: @BillSchanks Just to makes sure I am not mixing metaphors, does the job successfully save all files to staging but fail for all files when trying to move them to the business line (production)?

Comment: Correct it works fine for staging, always. but fails for the businss line path.

Comment: @BillSchanks Make sure the proxy account has write permissions to the business line folder path. Your IT Security group may only have confirmed read-only permissions. Also, does your account have write permissions? Does the job run successfully when you run it from your local (SSIS will use your credentials).

Comment: The IT Security Group did a write (create file) under the proxy account to success. For my account it doesn't have access at all to the path, so I can't run it under my id. I do have what we call Emergency ID's we can check out to run the packages for production issues. But I can't run Visual Studio under that Id, as the id doesn't have Internet Access and when I launch VS I try to sign in with my credentials but it can't reach the sign in server as the emergecy id can't access the web.

Comment: I can run it to success when I choose a diff path, but that doens't help the business line. All that proves is the package is valid. I've asked the IT Dept several times about it, but they keep saying the proxy account has all the access it needs (read, write, modify).

Comment: Any chance that error can come up if the drive is full? I asked the Businss Line to check that, but have not heard. It's not like Microsoft has perfect error messages, sometimes they are very mis-leading.

Comment: @BillSchanks Verify that the package is using the correct folder path and file name. If you are attempting to `move` the file, make sure that the variable is the folder path only (do not include file name). If you are attempting to `rename` the file then make sure the variable contains both the folder path and the file name.